# Recovering an old Multibit wallet file (76 characters long)

Tags: wallet-recovery, multibit

I have a wallet file from 2011 back when I used to play around with Bitcoin.

I used an old version of Multibit which has since long been unavailable.

My wallet looks like this:

```
# KEEP YOUR PRIVATE KEYS SAFE !
# Anyone who can read this file can spend your bitcoin.
#
# Format:
#   <Base58 encoded private key>[<whitespace>[<key createdAt>]]
#
#   The Base58 encoded private keys are the same format as
#   produced by the Satoshi client/ sipa dumpprivkey utility.
#
#   Key createdAt is in UTC format as specified by ISO 8601
#   e.g: 2011-12-31T16:42:00Z . The century, 'T' and 'Z' are mandatory
#
U2FsdGVXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXsnQhpZ6
 2013-10-30T20:52:01Z
# End of private keys
```

I managed to get a version of Multibit HD from the web archive but this doesn't support this wallet.

I also tried using OpenSSL with the following command:

```
openssl enc -d -p -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in C:\key\wallet.key.txt -out c:\key\wallet-decrypted.key.txt
```

This output a file which wasn't correct and gave a `bad decrypt` error. I know the password for this file.

Does anyone know the correct method of decrypting this?

UPDATE: While I'm at it, I found a whole bunch more .key files. This one has a different format:

```
org.bitcoin.productionm!œ;€ò=°´zXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXÌñ9,o( 2D
ä¢¦]5+¡XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXE}Û@nŸé(2

ÐáXXXXR#
org.multibit.walletProtect.2 ZYour wallet description`
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Does anyone know the correct method of decrypting this?**

It doesn't seem to be encrypted. The comments at the start of the file don't mention any form of encryption. It only mentions a common form of encoding - Base58. Encoding is not encryption so no decryption is needed.

> > `#   The` **`Base58`** `encoded private keys are the same format as`
> > `#   produced by the Satoshi client/ sipa` **`dumpprivkey`** `utility.`

That Base58 key ought to be able to be imported into several different modern wallet programs.

See

- [Private keys importing in format got by dumpprivkey](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/36876/13866)
- [How to get the private key in hex from the output of dumpprivkey](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/52951/13866)
- https://btcinformation.org/en/developer-reference#dumpprivkey

Answer (score 1):

If the priv key starts with U2 and ends with = its most probably an md5 encryption.

Your password seems wrong, so you would need something like btcrecover that would jog through irerations.

You can find it on github here
https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover

Good luck
/KX

Comment: I'm positive of the password though, long story but I remember the moment I set it up and the only password I used at the time etc. I will take a look at the GitHub repo. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In your case you have a few options:

1. **Using MultiBit Classic:** Since MultiBitHD doesn't support Classic wallets, you might want to find a MultiBit Classic executable. Install it in a secure, offline environment to avoid any potential security risks. Open your wallet with the correct password and use the "Export" feature to extract your keys.
2. **Handling a .key File with plaintext:**
   Your first .key file contains plaintext and the encrypted private key. You should remove everything except the encrypted private key (U2FsdG...snQhpZ6) and attempt to decrypt it again. If there are multiple keys, repeat this process for each one.
3. **Dealing with the Multibit Protobuf .key File:**
   The second .key file you have uses the Multibit protobuf format. You can decrypt this using [btcrecover](https://btcrecover.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with the following command:

```
python btcrecover.py --wallet ./btcrecover/test/test-wallets/multibit-wallet.key --correct-wallet-password [YOUR WALLET PASSWORD] --dump-privkeys multibit-wallet.key.privkeys.txt
```

After extracting the keys, you can import them into a different wallet like [Electrum](https://electrum.org/).