# Does anyone know why so many burn transactions are being sent to address 1111111111111111111114oLvT2 currently?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, mempool

The number of incoming transactions to 1111111111111111111114oLvT2 in the past 24 hours is enormous...

Edit: they are OP_RETURN txns, but each has two identical outputs to that burn address; I don't get it.

Comment: It’s stacks: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/70241/5406

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's with this address 1111111111111111111114oLvT2?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70241/whats-with-this-address-1111111111111111111114olvt2)

Comment: Do apps on Stacks have unique, fixed addresses like erc20 contracts? Becuase most txns seem to be sent from just a few addresses, some of which have had 10k+ btc pass through...

https://mempool.space/address/18hofVCQv8cMDpqDNqSXyrUDffq7MKLxiu

https://mempool.space/address/1Di1YoMov6Ua3gPedfQz7TkP6iTLqbPUzi

https://mempool.space/address/13ogR3PP3dUNbP62CBaxtdygYjPzUc17sb