# How can I prove that I destroyed some bit coins?

Tags: proof-of-destruction, destroy-bitcoins

If I wanted to destroy bitcoins, and prove that it was done (with relative certainty), what would I need to do?

Comment: Thanks! Although this is a duplicate, I'd like to leave it as a signpost to redirect people to the proper answers listed below.  (Assist with Google searches, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make it clear that you no longer own them you can just send yourself 1 santoshi and put the rest up as a fee. If you want to destroy them there are a couple decent address to send them to in [What is the Bitcoin equivalent of /dev/null?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3777/2630)

EDIT: there are better answers here: [How to generate a valid bitcoin address for destroying bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1851/how-to-generate-a-valid-bitcoin-address-for-destroying-bitcoins)

Comment: Paying the bitcoins as a fee doesn't work because you don't have to broadcast the transaction, you can just hold on to it until you find a block and collect the fee.

Comment: You could say that you are going to pay the fee in one hour. Then the probability that this person recollects the fee is directly proportional to their share of the computation power.